# When will AWS S3 delete the expired objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle

I have a AWS S3 bucket with a 1 day expiration lifecycle rule.  But the AWS didn’t delete the expired objects automatically. How can I let AWS delete the expired objects automatically? Are there still additional cost for these expired but unremoved objects?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No AWS will evaluate the expiration rules once in  a day and will not be charged for that as said in below doc.

> We evaluate the expiration rules once each day. During this time,
>   based on their expiration dates, any object found to be expired will
>   be queued for removal. You will not be billed for any associated
>   storage for those objects on or after their expiration date. If server
>   access logging has been enabled for that S3 bucket, an
>   S3.EXPIRE.OBJECT record will be generated when an object is removed.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/

Answer (score 22):

Please be aware that AWS only guarantees you will not be billed for expired objects. **AWS gives no guarantees when expired objects will actually be cleaned**.  In my experience, this is *usually* a day within expiring, but this week I ran into a production issue, because one of my Lambda's choked on the amount of objects in my S3 bucket, which is normally limited, due to a Lifecycle Policy I set on the bucket. An inquiry at Amazon AWS Support confirmed this:

> Thank you for the provided information, I have checked the LifeCycle Management for the eu-west-1 region and have noted that there has been a recent increase in the number of objects to be expired.
>   As the LifeCycle Manager is asynchronous for all S3 Buckets the region, increases in the number of objects to be expired can introduce longer delays [1].

So please be aware of this, when you're crafting your AWSome solutions!

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html